# Can I adjust the timeout on the python twistd server via a command line option?

Tags: ftp, timeout, twistd

I have a problem with a very slow network due to some bad hardware. It will eventually be fixed, but in the meantime I need to test some over the air upgrades of our software. The upgrade is a very large file and keeps timing out on the FTP server (twistd from the python twisted package).

Is there a way that I can on the twistd server side, presumably using a command line option, get it to not timeout, or to set the timeout to something very large like 24 hours? Or is the timeout a function of the client request?